# Autocompletion in bash script arguments

Tags: bash

I have a simple but use case for autocompletion. For example when I run:

```
run.sh arg1 'CPU 100 SETTING1 xxx SETTING2 xxx OUTPUT_DIR /home/user/prj2/record_xxx'
```

Usually arg1 can be autocompleted, but the path in arg2, which is a string, cannot be autocompleted. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: How did you autocomplete *arg1*?

Comment: @EmilyE. use `Tab` key

Comment: Yes right. Could you please post the code?

Answer (score 0):

One simple trick is to:

- close the single quote
- add a space
- start the path and type tab: it will autocomplete.

That is:

```
run.sh arg1 'CPU 100 SETTING1 xxx SETTING2 xxx OUTPUT_DIR' /home/user/prj<TAB>
                                                        ^^^
                                                       extra '
```

Then remove the extra `'`